# Whats the best practice to send multiple POST

Tags: ios, swift, post, nsurlsession

in My iOS app I have a requirement to post multiple data packets (as different POST requests) to be posted, Currently I am creating different NSURL sessions per request , And I am facing an issue where I have some 20 or more packets in queue and When I post all of them one by one only few are going throuw, rest I am getting **time out error**,

My analysis is that as [HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407597-httpmaximumconnectionsperhost) is 4 by default in iOS i.e we can have only 4 parallel connections simultaniously with in a session, other requests are going to suspeneded state and eventually I am getting timeout error

**How do I better handle this issue?**

**Is that fine if I set HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost to some 100 ??**

following is the code for posting the data, **And I am posting multiple packets by calling the below function in for loop**

```
func send(_ request: URLRequest, completionHandler handler: handler?) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            handler?(respHandler(inData: data as Data?, inResponse: response, inError: error as NSError?))
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple queue, where you will put URLSessionDataTask.
Then take one task from queue, call resume method and when task is finished do similar action for other tasks in queue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, dataTask.resume() anyways operates on backbround thread, how does it add value by using NSOperationQueue?

Comment: It's not necessary but you can use NSOperationQueue, then you have to subclass NSOperation which take URLSessionDataTask. Similar concept can be found here https://gist.github.com/doschi/c628e4ad431dffc57d13

Comment: Still I dont understand How it will solve my problem, Even now all the requests are executed in separate secondary thread

Comment: Yes and it's correct, all request by default are async. You have to manually serialize them.